# Running SQLCMD in a Batch Script for local .sql file on local SQLSERVEREXPRESS2014 throwing 'Access Denied' error

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a created a .sql file that will update a table in a data warehouse I am creating using SQL Server 2014 Express. Since Express does not support scheduling jobs, I am attempting to use a batch script scheduled in task scheduler to accomplish this.

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO This is running to update the [Table Name] Table in the SQL Server Database
PAUSE
sqlcmd -S [ComputerName]\SQLEXPRESS2014 -U myusername -P mypassword -i "My Path With Spaces" of [MyQuery].sql
ECHO Query Worked!
PAUSE
```

However, when I run it (even as Administrator), it denies me access. I am the administrator on this computer and the SQL Server Express 2014 service is local to my machine. I appreciate any advise the community may be able to provide here. :)

Comment: Try `SQLCMD -S (local)\SQLEXPRESS2014`.  Also note that being in the Administrators group in and of itself doesn't give you any permissions to access an SQL instance.  It's been that way since at least SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks! I used -E to access the instance, now I'm having trouble with my query only executing the first of my many lines.

Comment: If anyone sees this and is having a similar problem; my ultimate solution was to write a C# executable file that opened the connection to the database, read the query from the .sql file, and then executed that query against the database. Task scheduler, even with /c start "WINDOW NAME" "mypath" won't run a long query. No clue why. However, task scheduler will run an .exe file without issue.